# How to register a specific extension for my app?

Tags: java, android

im trying to register my app with specific extension and i want to open app 
with .myType files .
this code works for android 4.4:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.dak" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but it doesn't work for android versions later than 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

> this code works for android 4.4 :

No, it only works for `Uri` values that have the `file` scheme.

> but above code doesnt work for above android versions

No, it does not work for `Uri` values with a different scheme, such as `content`. The version of Android does not change that. More and more apps are using a scheme other than `file`, particularly on newer Android versions, as [the `file` scheme was (mostly) banned as of Android 7.0](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

You are welcome to also support `<data android:scheme="content" />`. However, file extensions are uncommon with `content`-scheme `Uri` values.

> im trying to register my app with specific extension

That has never been a particularly good plan on Android, and its viability is decreasing with each passing year.

Comment: whats your suggest to fix this problem?

Comment: @SabihFarhangi: I would not bother with custom file extensions. Rather that expecting outside apps to be able to open your app on content (push), offer an "open" option within your own app (pull) via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: This is not true, I have xiaomi phone and when i click .csv file in file manager Excel and Quickedit pop up.. I registered my file for csv and it works from gmail , probably it works there by content and content type intent filter I made but still I cannot mimic what these apps do for now

Comment: @Renetik: "I have xiaomi phone and when i click .csv file in file manager Excel and Quickedit pop up" -- the details of how that works, and how much it depends on the file extension, is tied to the file manager, Excel, and Quickedit. My guess is that it is working using MIME types, not file extensions.

Comment: @CommonsWare thumbs-up man you where right , they used mimeType text/comma-separated-values that I have never seen , instead of text/csv and application/csv I was already handling... so yes everything ok here now